# Keras throws shape error even though I'm giving it the correct shape

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a simple conditional VAE model. On runtime I feed the decoder noise and labels

```
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1.0, size=(2,))  
decoder.predict([noise,labels])
```

I then get the following error:

`ValueError: Error when checking : expected decoder_noise to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)`

In the graph I also see that it expects an array of `(2,)` as shown in the image below.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Note: `labels` has shape `(4,)` so I'm not accidentally swapping them.

[image: vae_array_dim]

Comment: do label.reshape(-1,2) or (2,-1)

Comment: @Paddy that didn't work

Comment: please provide code of your model and data shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need give an 2D array of noise not just `(2,)` for every label you have. In this case your noise should have `size=(4,2)` so for every sample you get `(2,)` which is what the model expects.

The takeaway message is that the first dimension tells the number of samples, labels is a scalar so you have `(4,)` but noise is not. So for every sample you need noise, hence `(4,2)`.

Comment: That's strange because if I remove the concatenation of inputs in Keras and concat the noise with the labels before I feed it into the decoder it works fine. However, now that I have split the label and noise as 2 inputs, the model freaks out.